# searching samsung tv emulator 3.5 (2012)

Tags: eclipse, samsung-smart-tv

I have been able to test my apps with the samsung emulator 4.5 and 5.1 so far.

Now I am looking for the samsung tv emulator 3.5 (2012). Does anyone know where I can download this emulator?